# Django choicefield iniital value problem

Tags: django, default, choicefield

I have a dynamic choice field:

```
PASSENGER_TYPE_CHOICE = [(p.id, p.cabin.name) for p in flight.passengertype_set.all() if p.availableSeats > 0]
self.fields['passenger_type'] = forms.ChoiceField(label=str(self.flight.code)+" Seat Type", initial=PASSENGER_TYPE_CHOICE[0][0],choices=PASSENGER_TYPE_CHOICE)
```

Notice that I put an initial value for it. But when I click the submit button for this form, it raises "This field is required". When I click the choicefield and select an option, it works. But do i really have to select first, even when there is an initial value? Please help?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#initial) says: To specify dynamic initial data, see the Form.initial parameter.

So this should do the trick:

```
form = MyPassengerForm(initial = {'passenger_type': PASSENGER_TYPE_CHOICE[0][0]})
```